# Access files in POST in NUXT3 API

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to understand what is expected way for accessing file data in POST method.

In ExpressJS that data is usually accessible through `req` like this: `req.files`

However `req.files` is undefined in Nuxt3 server endpoint. Do I need to use server-middleware to include files to the request? Or are there any other ways to achieve it?

Edit 1:

I was able to print our body using `const body = await useBody(req);`

However, now I'm struggling to figure out how to parse it properly.

Answer (score 3):

Use `readBody`.

```
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) =>
  const body = await readBody(event)
  return { body } 
})
```

Note: `useBody` is deprecated to replace with [readBody](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/server#handling-requests-with-body).

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same issue and have ended up with `formidable`.

My working post file looks like this:

```
import formidable from "formidable";

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const form = formidable({ multiples: true });

  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    form.parse(event.node.req, (err, fields, files) => {
      Object.keys(files).map((fileName) => {
        // do something with file
      })

      resolve();
    });
  });
})
```

Promise is needed to make multiple files upload work properly. See https://github.com/unjs/h3/issues/43#issuecomment-1069225214

Answer (score -1):

You can deconstruct for items received:

```js
import { useBody } from 'h3'

const body = await useBody(req);

const { files } = body;
```

Comment: Nice, wasn't aware of this, I will give it a try and see if that works.

Comment: https://github.com/unjs/h3/blob/main/src/utils/body.ts I don't them exporting files, it only returns json or rawBody from what I can tell

Comment: This does not work

Comment: useBody is deprecated